# Turn off the large parentheses

Tags: calc

I ultimately got annoyed of Calc's new displaying of parentheses

[image]

Here it's vaguely tolerable (you may however notice the presence of artifacts), but for complicated expressions the various graphical characters are often misaligned and I'd like to turn off, today and forever, this new feature of Calc.

I have cursorily checked the Calc menu, but I have not found an option related to what I want.

---

As requested in the comments, here it is how I get the big parentheses modulo the artifacts, that depend, as discussed below, on using Consolas.

1. Start Emacs loading no init files, neither system's nor user's

   ```
   emacs -Q
   ```
2. Start Calc in a single window

   ```
   M-x calc RET C-x 1
   ```
3. Type a "tall" expression that needs parentheses

   ```
   '(3/x + 5/y) a RET
   ```

At this point Emacs displays

```
        ⎛3   5⎞
1:  a * ⎜- + -⎟
        ⎝x   y⎠
```

---

I've realized it's the fault of the font I'm using, i.e., Consolas.
All the other monospaced fonts that I checked show an artifact-less behaviour!

---

Previously I voted to close my question.
Now I decide to retreat my closing vote because, even if changing the font removes the artifacts, the mechanism that activates/deactivates the display of big parentheses is worth to be explained.
Also, note the title of the question, it's not so much about removing the artifacts, but about turning off the big parentheses.

Comment: I couldn't find any mention of this in the NEWS files. Which version of Emacs does this? I don't seem to get this behavior but I'm not sure what to do to get it: can you give a recipe from scratch?

Comment: @NickD I'm sorry I cannot be more precise, I'd say a couple of years but I won't bet on it. It's one of those things that annoy you but stay in a corner of your field of view, until it's enough...

Comment: @NickD I have access to a Suse Tumbleweed and a Debian Sid notebooks, and on both systems I have the same behaviour. And I swear that I have not opted for a new behaviour!

Comment: What version of emacs?  Do `M-x emacs-version` to find out.

Comment: @FranBurstall GNU Emacs 29.1 (build 2, x86_64-suse-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.38, cairo version 1.18.0) on Suse, and a similarly recent 29.1 on Debian (that I have not handy at the moment)

Comment: Can you give a step-by-step way to see what you see? Start with `emacs -Q`, do `M-x calc` and then do - what? In fact, can you reproduce the behavior if you start with `emacs -Q`?

Comment: @NickD In the end I've realized that it's the font (Consolas) that I'm using. What can be seen in the question's picture is an artifact of the font. Now I have a dilemma: I like Consolas, I like it very much, but…

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I based it on a misunderstanding.

Comment: But how do you get large parens? I still don't know how to do that and I was hoping you could enlighten us.

Comment: @NickD I get large parentheses also when I start Emacs with `emacs -Q`, i.e., w/o loading no init files, neither system's nor user's. Or, in other words, I cannot tell how I got them activated in the first place.

Comment: @NickD Using `emacs -Q` is what made me realize that I was misunderstanding the reason of the artifacts.

Comment: Here we are. I have large parentheses and I want to turn them off, most people have no large parentheses and they want to turn them on, and everyone is walking in the dark!

Comment: I decided to retract my closing vote because I realize that understanding the big parentheses on/off mechanism is worth an answer in itself.

Comment: But you should edit the question to explain: the question should stand on its own and you should include *all* the information from the comments. In particular, my comment that starts "Can you give a step-by-step ..." still needs to be confronted. Start with `emacs -Q`, type `M-x calc` and then type what exactly?

Answer (score 2):

You have Calc in Big language mode. See [chapter 7.8.1 Normal Language Modes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Normal-Language-Modes.html) of the Emacs Calc manual for more details. This causes calc to format algebraic expressions in a manner closer to paper notation. In the calc buffer, `d N` will switch to normal language mode which won’t have tall parentheses. `d B` switches back to Big language mode.

As you have discovered, the precise appearance of the tall parentheses depends on your chosen font. Not every font uses every trick, or supports every obscure feature perfectly, so a great deal of variation is to be expected. The font I use, Input Mono Condensed, doesn’t even have the stretchy parentheses; Emacs ends up substituting Fixed Semicondensed instead, which isn’t quite the same size:

[image: Big language mode with Input Mono Condensed]

Comment: Thanks for this! I still don't understand how the OP got the Big Language as default though.

Comment: Yea, I don’t really see how that happened either but it doesn’t really change the answer. The real question is what were they on when they implemented it?